# pandas dataframe groupby rank generates unexpected order of ranking

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, rank

I am using the following code to generate the rank column,

`df["rank"] = df.groupby(['group1','userId'])[['rank_level1','rank_level2']].rank(method='first', ascending=True).astype(int)`

but as you can see in the following example data it is generating the wrong order of ranking considering rank_level2 column

expected_Rank is the ranking order I am expecting

| group1 | userId | geoId | rank_level1 | rank_level2 | rank | expected_Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | q | 3 | 3.506102795 | 1 | 8 |
| a | 1 | w | 3 | -9.359613563 | 2 | 2 |
| a | 1 | e | 3 | -2.368458072 | 3 | 3 |
| a | 1 | r | 3 | 13.75731938 | 4 | 9 |
| a | 1 | t | 3 | 0.229777761 | 5 | 5 |
| a | 1 | y | 3 | -10.25124866 | 6 | 1 |
| a | 1 | u | 3 | 2.82822285 | 7 | 7 |
| a | 1 | i | 3 | 0 | 8 | 4 |
| a | 1 | o | 3 | 1.120593402 | 9 | 6 |
| a | 1 | p | 4 | 1.98 | 10 | 10 |
| a | 1 | z | 4 | 5.110299374 | 11 | 11 |
| b | 1 | p | 2 | -9.552317622 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 1 | r | 3 | 1.175083121 | 2 | 6 |
| b | 1 | t | 3 | 0 | 3 | 5 |
| b | 1 | o | 3 | 9.383253146 | 4 | 8 |
| b | 1 | w | 3 | 5.782528196 | 5 | 7 |
| b | 1 | i | 3 | -0.680999413 | 6 | 4 |
| b | 1 | y | 3 | -0.990387248 | 7 | 3 |
| b | 1 | e | 3 | -11.18793533 | 8 | 2 |
| b | 1 | z | 3 | 12.33791512 | 9 | 9 |
| b | 1 | u | 4 | -4.799979138 | 10 | 11 |
| b | 1 | q | 4 | -25.92 | 11 | 10 |

Comment: your code to generate the `rank` column doesn't work as you provided it. It can't take two columns and only return only one.

Comment: It does work for me, I am not sure why it isn't working for you. I just anonymized the column names that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create tuples by both columns and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) and `method='dense'`:

```
df["rank"] = (df.assign(new=df[['rank_level1','rank_level2']].agg(tuple, 1))
                .groupby(['group1','userId'])['new']
                .transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='dense', ascending=True))
                .astype(int))

print (df)
   group1  userId geoId  rank_level1  rank_level2  rank  expected_Rank
0       a       1     q            3     3.506103     8              8
1       a       1     w            3    -9.359614     2              2
2       a       1     e            3    -2.368458     3              3
3       a       1     r            3    13.757319     9              9
4       a       1     t            3     0.229778     5              5
5       a       1     y            3   -10.251249     1              1
6       a       1     u            3     2.828223     7              7
7       a       1     i            3     0.000000     4              4
8       a       1     o            3     1.120593     6              6
9       a       1     p            4     1.980000    10             10
10      a       1     z            4     5.110299    11             11
11      b       1     p            2    -9.552318     1              1
12      b       1     r            3     1.175083     6              6
13      b       1     t            3     0.000000     5              5
14      b       1     o            3     9.383253     8              8
15      b       1     w            3     5.782528     7              7
16      b       1     i            3    -0.680999     4              4
17      b       1     y            3    -0.990387     3              3
18      b       1     e            3   -11.187935     2              2
19      b       1     z            3    12.337915     9              9
20      b       1     u            4    -4.799979    11             11
21      b       1     q            4   -25.920000    10             10
```

because:

```
df["rank"] = df.assign(new=df[['rank_level1','rank_level2']].agg(tuple, 1)).groupby(['group1','userId'])['new'].rank(method='first', ascending=True).astype(int)
```

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate